# Select to constructor OneToMany relationship in QueryDsl

Tags: java, hibernate, querydsl

I want to select elements from a database using QueryDsl.

```
    final QUserEntity user = QUserEntity.userEntity;
    new JPAQuery<UserResponse>(em)
                    .select(Projections.constructor(User.class, user.id, user.name, 
                            Projections.constructor(AddressResponse.class, user.address.id, user.address.name), 
                            user.pets))
                    .from(user).fetch();
```

I want this to use the constructor in User:

```
public UserResponse(final String id, final String name, final AddressResponse address, Set<pets> pets) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.pets = pets;
}
```

The user and address works fine, but I don't know how to handle the pets, which is a OneToMany-entity and thus a set of entities.

'Pets' has the following relation in User:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = 'petId', referencedColumnName = 'petId')
private Set<Pet> pets;
```

However, when I try to run this a I get the following error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

And the generated SQL has a syntax error:

```
SELECT
  chargepoin0_.userid    AS col_0_0_,
  chargepoin0_.username  AS col_1_0_,
  chargepoin0_.addressid   AS col_2_0_,
  addressent5_.addressname AS col_3_0_,.AS col_4_0_, pets6_.itemid AS itemid1_4_, pets6_.connected AS connecte2_4_, pets6_.objectstatecode AS objectst3_4_ FROM user user0_
```

Thanks in advance,
Markus

Comment: Same for me on OneToMany and ManyToMany using PostgreSQL. Seems not a connector issue